# How to disable default maxlength of input field?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I just discovered that Chrome seems to have a default maxlength setting for input fields in html. I only can insert a string with length 8649.

Is there a method to increase this maxlength?

Comment: Why, do you have a page letting the user write a book???

Comment: Are you using `input` or `textarea`?

Comment: Anyway, maybe an input is not the suitable element for this task, what about editable div or a textarea? **This question smells like a troll...**

Comment: Im using an input. It was just a discovery while playing around and its more a research question because I dont see why browsers should limit these, not to such a value.

Comment: what if you add maxlength=8650 to the input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, Chrome has no default value for `maxlength`, and I can enter 10,000 characters in an `input` field (on Chrome 20 beta, Win 7). You may have tested with actual form submission using GET method, in which case there may be browser-dependent and server-dependent restrictions on the total length of form data.

Inspecting the DOM on Chrome, an `input` element has no default `maxlength`, but it has `maxLength`, with the value 524288.